# SQL split values with same ID from 2 tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I have 2 tables (that's retrieving data from a main table). Example:

Table1

```
       id      GroupX     Source    GroupNum     Amount  
-------------------------------------------------------
 1     23      School     SH001     1            700  
 2     23      Bank       BA001     2            300  
 3     23      Music      MU001     3            500  
 4     23      School     SH999     1            900
```

Table2

```
     id    GroupNum     SourceAmt
----------------------------------
1    23    1            700  
2    23    2            100  
3    23    3            500  
4    23    1            900
```

My dilemma is with the query I'm using. It's returning additional rows for split values(notice in table 2 "GroupNum" has a split value of 700 and 900)

My results should be

```
     id    GroupX     Source    GroupNum     Amount     SourceAmt  
-----------------------------------------------------------------
 1   23    School     SH001     1            700        700  
 2   23    Bank       BA001     2            300        100  
 3   23    Music      MU001     3            500        500  
 4   23    School     SH999     1            900        900
```

But instead I get this

```
     id    GroupX    Source     GroupNum     Amount     SourceAmt  
-----------------------------------------------------------------
 1   23    School     SH001     1            700        700  
 2   23    School     SH001     1            700        900  
 3   23    Bank       BA001     2            300        100  
 4   23    Music      MU001     3            500        500  
 5   23    School     SH999     1            900        900  
 6   23    School     SH999     1            900        700
```

Here's my query:

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.GroupX,
    t1.Source,
    t1.GroupNum,
    t1.Amount,
    t2.SourceAmt
FROM 
    table1 as t1
INNER JOIN 
    table2 as t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
                 AND t1.GroupNum = t2.GroupNum
WHERE 
    t1.id = 23
```

I've tried using Distinct as well. Assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which values for `Source`, `Amount`, and `SourceAmt` do you want the query to choose when you group your records?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you would like to join Table1 and Table2 such that the `id`, `GroupNum`, and **amounts** align. If this is indeed the case, then you'll need to join on the amounts as well, e.g.,:

```
Select t1.id, t1.Group, t1.Source, t1.GroupNum, t1.Amount, t2.SourceAmt
From table1 as t1 INNER JOIN
     table2 as t2 
     ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.GroupNum = t2.GroupNum AND t1.Amount = t2.SourceAmt
where id = 23
```

If this is *not* what you want, or you would prefer not to join using the amounts (e.g., you cannot guarantee that you won't see the same amount more than once), then you're in a bit of a conundrum; you'll note that (`id`, `GroupNum`) tuples are not unique in either table, and thus your join is not one-to-one. You may want to include `Source` in `table2` or otherwise provide a `transactionId` in table1 that maps onto a unique ID column in `table2`.

Comment: . . I'm not sure this is what the OP intends, but it is a correct solution.

Comment: The query does eliminate the unnecessary rows however t1.Amount = t2.SourceAmt will not work.  SourceAmt can be different from Amount.

Comment: in this case @GordonLinoff's response will work as his approach constructs ad hoc join keys to ensure a 1:1 join. that said, if these are your tables and should this be a common operation, you should consider modifying them to include such keys so that you can avoid such an ad hoc approach in the future, simplifying the join and, using indices, improving performance.

Answer (score 1):

You need an additional `join` key.  There is no obvious candidate, except perhaps for amount -- but I'm not sure that is what you intend.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so there is no concept of matching by "line number".

You can assign a row number using `row_number()`.  The following will do the match, but you need to specify the ordering column:

```
Select t1.id, t1.Group, t1.Source, t1.GroupNum, t1.Amount, t2.SourceAmt
From (select t1.*,
             row_number() over (partition by t1.id order by ?) as seqnum
      from table1 t1
     ) t1 inner join
     (select t2.*
             row_number() over (partition by t1.id order by ?) as seqnum
      from table2 t2 
     ) t2
     on t1.id = t2.id and t1.GroupNum = t2.GroupNum and
        t1.seqnum = t2.seqnum
where id = 23 ;
```

The `?` is for the ordering column in each table.

Comment: my bad for posting right before you did...i saw your edits but wasn't sure whether you were having a go at an answer as well.

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer Gordon Linoff .  I've spent hours trying to get the right results and this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would choose a different approach from simple `INNER JOIN`, simply because you can do limited things with that result set (here's the result set from that inner join)

[image]

I would do multiple joins.

First I would `LEFT JOIN` with the default condition + `where table1.[Amount] = table2.[SourceAmt]`. This will give me set where `[Amount]` and `[SourceAmt]` are equal

After this I `INNER JOIN` with the default condition to get the Amounts that doesn't match

Here's the query

```
with t1 as
(
    select 23 as [id], 'School' as [Group], 'SH001' as [Source], 1 as [GroupNum], 700 as [Amount]
    union all
    select 23, 'Bank', 'BA001', 2, 300
    union all
    select 23, 'Music', 'MU001', 3, 500
    union all
    select 23, 'School', 'SH999', 1, 900
),
t2 as
(
    select 23 as [id], 1 as [GroupNum], 700 as [SourceAmt]
    union all
    select 23, 2, 100
    union all
    select 23, 3, 500
    union all
    select 23, 1, 900
)
select t1.*, a.*, b.*
from t1 
left join t2 as a on 
    t1.[id]       = a.[id] 
and t1.[GroupNum] = a.[GroupNum]
and t1.[Amount]   = a.[SourceAmt]
inner join t2 as b on
    t1.[id]       =  b.[id]
and t1.[GroupNum] =  b.[GroupNum]
where t1.[id] = 23
```

And here's the result set, which you can inspect
[image]

Now, I use this result as my pre-result actually, and do a little trick with `CASE` and `[takeIt]` column, here's the final query

```
with t1 as
(
    select 23 as [id], 'School' as [Group], 'SH001' as [Source], 1 as [GroupNum], 700 as [Amount]
    union all
    select 23, 'Bank', 'BA001', 2, 300
    union all
    select 23, 'Music', 'MU001', 3, 500
    union all
    select 23, 'School', 'SH999', 1, 900
),
t2 as
(
    select 23 as [id], 1 as [GroupNum], 700 as [SourceAmt]
    union all
    select 23, 2, 100
    union all
    select 23, 3, 500
    union all
    select 23, 1, 900
),
res as
(
    select t1.[id],
           t1.[Group],
           t1.[Source],
           t1.[GroupNum],
           t1.[Amount],
           isnull(a.[SourceAmt], b.[SourceAmt]) as [SourceAmt],
           case when a.[SourceAmt] is null or a.[SourceAmt] = b.[SourceAmt] then 1
                else 0
           end as [takeIt]
    from t1 
    left join t2 as a on 
        t1.[id]       = a.[id] 
    and t1.[GroupNum] = a.[GroupNum]
    and t1.[Amount]   = a.[SourceAmt]
    inner join t2 as b on
        t1.[id]       = b.[id]
    and t1.[GroupNum] = b.[GroupNum]
    where t1.[id] = 23
)
select [id],
       [Group],
       [Source],
       [GroupNum],
       [Amount],
       [SourceAmt]
from res
where [takeIt] = 1
```